# Executing karateDSL scenarios with mocks in IntelliJ

Tags: mocking, karate

I have been trying to use karate mocks and failed when executing with the IntelliJ. I am not using the standalone mocks. I want to invoke the mocks with tests. Is it not possible to execute tests with intelliJ when mocks are being used?

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#embedding In fact all the Karate regression tests start mocks from the Java API. Here is just one example: [`ConsumerUsingMockTest.java`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/mock/contract/ConsumerUsingMockTest.java)

Comment: If we use the Java API to start the mock as in the example given above, will it be invoked when .feature is executed with IntelliJ?

Comment: no. if you are using IntelliJ, why not make use of the JUnit features ? but if you really want to run *only* the feature, then you have to init the mock via JS and this is explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#within-a-karate-test - sorry it can't get any simpler

Comment: Thank you. I think I got the idea and I'm going with embedding. In that case how will running tests will work? can I execute like "java -jar karate.jar my-test.feature"?

Comment: since embedding needs some complexity I personally recommend Java code. the answer to your question is "JUnit" talk to a Java friend if you need to. you *can* however create a small feature file to just start the mock - as I linked in my comment above. all the best !

Comment: Thanks you for the kind responses, I found the new starting mock 'Within a Karate Test' to be much helpful. The problem I faced was when I use "java -jar karate.jar my-test.feature" run the tests it will not start the mock. Am I doing it wrong and is there any other way to run tests with mock?